# Laravel 5 - Is it possible to work with a MySQL database without using Eloquent or Artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

I´m a new user of Laravel framework. I see that it uses Eloquent with Artisan to handle the interaction with the database.

For now, I have already a complete database inside my mysql server. What mean I dont want to pass through all the steps to create schemas and create Models based on my tables.

So my question is if it is possible to create a regular connection to my database and use it like a regular queries? If yes how can I accomplish this task?

Unfortunately I only find tutorials for Laravel relationship with databases using ORM stuffs.
That is good but that will be my next learning step.

Comment: If you think "ORM stuff is good but your next learning step", you're way ahead when using Laravel. Before using PHP frameworks at all, try and make your own, simple ORM and maybe even make a tiny framework. Most frameworks cover up waaaay too many things which makes things even harder to understand if you don't have a basic understanding of some of the most common design patterns.

Comment: You can run pure php inside of Laravel. You're much better off using eloquent because of the amount of work it saves, prepared statements, integration etc. You can also address a pre-existing db using Eloquent. I just converted a cold fusion site to laravel and eloquent Just Worked(tm). It's actually fairly easy once you work with it for a bit. You're better off just using Eloquent. The learning curve for using it within laravel is pretty minimal.

Comment: did you check https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended ? It seems like you need something like this to autogenerate your models.

Comment: I suggest you create a few models. For example the user model is kind of important when it comes to authentication. However you don't need to create models for each and every table you have. You can just use fluent to create queries.

Comment: The issue for now is that I have a database with 160 tables and I dont have time to pass all this to Eloquent and ORM models. I was develloping my own ORM, but Laravel is nice and better than mine. But for now, that will be the next step. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Eloquent, but it does make things nicer. Laravel has the [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) that you can use instead.

Artisan is how you can use Laravel on the command line, for things like adding migrations for tables (adding tables/columns) and seeding tables, among other things. It usually doesn't come into play for most web-based calls.

Comment: Yes  I agree with you. Eloquent is nice. But for now I have a databse with 160 tables and I dont have time to write all statements to Eloquent to create models. That will be done in the future. For now I just want to connect laravel to the database and do the stuffs. So, I was reading the link you sent, all that I need is to create a new controller and strat the queries correct?

Comment: You only need a new controller if you don't have any. You can use DB statements inline with your code and existing controllers.